# The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, path

I started learning node.js and faced with a problem. Tell me, what is my mistake?

I created a file with text

```
const writeFileAsync = async (path, data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => fs.writeFile(path, data, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject('Create file failed');
        }
        resolve()
        console.log('File created')
    }))
}
```

Add text to file

```
const appendFileAsync = async (path, data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => fs.appendFile(path, data, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject('Append text failed')
        }
        resolve()
        console.log('Append text successful')
    }))
}
```

I get "Failed to catch". What's wrong? Why it isn't working?

```
writeFileAsync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'new-folder', 'new-text-file.txt'), 'I\'m feeling so boring sometimes')
    .then(() => appendFileAsync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'new-folder', 'new-text-file.txt'), '. ' + path.sep + ' Also I wanna say that I love eating'))
    .then(() => appendFileAsync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'new-folder', 'new-text-file.txt'), ' ' + ' and can cook something interesting'))
    .then(() => appendFileAsync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'new-folder', 'new-text-file.txt'), '. ' + path.sep + ' So, it is a first time when i\'m creating app like this.'))
    .catch(err => console.log('failed to catch'))
```

When i used: `console.log(writeFileAsync())`, I get: Promise {  }
(node:1880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

```
at Object.writeFile (fs.js:1436:5)
at G:\node\lesson-one\process\file-system.js:41:45

at new Promise (<anonymous>)

at writeFileAsync (G:\node\lesson-one\process\file-system.js:41:9)

at Object.<anonymous> (G:\node\lesson-one\process\file-system.js:72:13)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)

at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
```

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:1880) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
failed to catch

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, by the way. [`fs` has a promise API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v19.x/docs/api/fs.html#promises-api). (Plus, you are currently swallowing useful error information.)

Comment: Also, can you please include the error stack in your post?

Comment: @CherryDT I did it but my knowledge is not enough to understand and resolve this

Comment: I can't see any problem in what you showed, are you sure this is the actual code that's run? What exactly is in `G:\node\lesson-one\process\file-system.js` at lines 41 and 72, please?

Comment: @CherryDT `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => fs.writeFile(path, data, (err) => {` at lines 41. `console.log(writeFileAsync())` at line 72. Yes, I'm sure. If you remove line 72, then the result will be `failed to catch'. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: OK, so the problem is clear: `writeFileAsync()` has no arguments in line 72, so both `path` and `data` will be `undefined`. You then call `fs.writeFile(undefined, undefined, ...)` and it rightfully complains.

Comment: And as for `failed to catch`: The issue is that you swallow the error, so you won't know what it is. Log it instead! (`console.log('failed:', err)` - important to use `,` and not `+` here to avoid coercing to string and losing stack) - or remove the `.catch` entirely and you will get an unhandled promise rejection which also shows the error.

Comment: However, it will likely just be `Write text failed`, because you also swallow the error _there_... You should simply do `reject(err)` at that point. (Or, as I mentioned, use the promise API to begin with - much simpler.)

Comment: My psychic debugging powers further tell me that once you fixed both places at which you were swallowing errors, you will probably discover that the error is `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\node\lesson-one\process\new-folder'`, and the reason for that is that in order to create a file in a folder, that folder has to exist first.

Comment: @CherryDT Yes, you're right. I got the error `no such file or directory`. I really had a mistake on the way that I didn't notice. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @CherryDT Using line 72, I wanted to see what the error was, but in the end it only created new errors, now I understand that it was a stupid idea.